How can I avoid unbalanced memory usage when performing multi-gpu training using Huggingface Trainer?
I am attempting to fine-tune Google's flan-t5-large model (only 783M parameters, so it can easily fit on a much smaller single GPU than any of the ones I'm using) on multiple GPUs using the HuggingFace Seq2Seq trainer. I'm using a Standard_NC96ads_A100_v4 compute instance in Azure ML Studio which has 4 80 GB A100 GPUs, 96 CPUs, and 880 GB of system RAM. I am using a batch size of 2 and not evaluating at all (by the time the run crashes, anyways). Here are the full Seq2Seq training arguments I'm using:
train_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir=args.output_dir,
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    logging_steps = 1,
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=2,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=50,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    save_total_limit=3,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    predict_with_generate=True,
    fp16=False,
    bf16=True,
    push_to_hub=False,
    report_to="wandb"
)

Despite this, after training for some number of iterations (varies between 600 and 1000 records processed out of a ~100k record training set) I always get a CUDA OOM error. Unfortunately weights and biases wasn't super helpful as it doesn't poll the memory usage often enough to capture spikes, but I did some command line logging and found this:
Here is the formatted table for Stack Overflow:



Date
Time
GPU
FB (MB)
BAR1 (MB)
CCPM (MB)
SM (%)
MEM (%)
ENC (%)
DEC (%)
JPG (%)
OFA (%)




20240607
03:24:30
0
4179
4
0
11
1
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:30
1
4787
4
0
12
7
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:30
2
4857
4
0
24
7
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:30
3
4749
4
0
10
4
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:31
0
2985
4
0
32
1
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:31
1
4831
4
0
13
5
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:31
2
11313
4
0
42
27
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:31
3
10721
4
0
12
9
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:32
0
3699
4
0
18
1
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:32
1
3955
4
0
24
1
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:32
2
4055
4
0
28
1
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:32
3
3997
4
0
31
2
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:33
0
4823
4
0
9
3
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:33
1
6911
4
0
22
14
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:33
2
15361
4
0
61
38
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:33
3
13857
4
0
9
7
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:34
0
2983
4
0
13
6
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:34
1
3571
4
0
22
9
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:34
2
7821
4
0
20
7
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:34
3
8287
4
0
10
6
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:35
0
3607
4
0
25
1
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:35
1
4891
4
0
25
3
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:35
2
9335
4
0
31
15
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:35
3
8521
4
0
32
16
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:36
0
3167
4
0
32
1
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:36
1
6759
4
0
16
0
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:36
2
15201
4
0
32
18
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:36
3
13407
4
0
49
30
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:37
0
4165
4
0
20
1
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:37
1
4757
4
0
20
8
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:37
2
4947
4
0
18
9
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:37
3
5045
4
0
16
9
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:38
0
4183
4
0
17
1
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:38
1
4759
4
0
13
2
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:38
2
4909
4
0
26
2
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:38
3
4027
4
0
18
2
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:39
0
5121
4
0
1
0
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:39
1
37061
4
0
46
1
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:39
2
44995
4
0
89
9
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:39
3
4817
4
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:40
0
5121
4
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:40
1
37061
4
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:40
2
78125
4
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


20240607
03:24:40
3
4817
4
0
0
0
0
0
0
0



Clearly there is a large memory spike that causes GPU 2 to completely fill up, however across all 4 GPUs only 39% of total memory is used. I have much longer logs documenting most of the run, and noticed that this spiky memory usage is consistent throughout, it just managed to run until that point before one of the spikes was big enough to completely fill one of the GPUs. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that there is any consistent pattern in when the spikiness occurs; this entire run occurred well before any additional operations like saving a model checkpoint or running evaluation would have occurred.
I tried DeepSpeed as well and the run actually ran out of memory even earlier; for the sake of completeness this is the configuration I used:
{
  "bf16": {
    "enabled": "auto"
  },
  "optimizer": {
    "type": "AdamW",
    "params": {
      "lr": "auto",
      "betas": "auto",
      "eps": "auto",
      "weight_decay": "auto"
    }
  },
  "scheduler": {
    "type": "WarmupLR",
    "params": {
      "warmup_min_lr": "auto",
      "warmup_max_lr": "auto",
      "warmup_num_steps": "auto"
    }
  },
  "zero_optimization": {
    "stage": 2,
    "offload_optimizer": {
        "device": "cpu",
        "pin_memory": true
    },
    "allgather_partitions": true,
    "allgather_bucket_size": 2e8,
    "overlap_comm": true,
    "reduce_scatter": true,
    "reduce_bucket_size": 2e8,
    "contiguous_gradients": true
  },
  "gradient_accumulation_steps": "auto",
  "gradient_clipping": "auto",
  "steps_per_print": 2000,
  "train_batch_size": "auto",
  "train_micro_batch_size_per_gpu": "auto",
  "wall_clock_breakdown": false
}

Finally, it doesn't seem to be the case that memory fragmentation is the issue, as the error message reads:
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 4.81 GiB. GPU  has a total capacity of 79.15 GiB of which 2.86 GiB is free. Process 27719 has 76.29 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 74.19 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 1.59 GiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=expandable_segments:True to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management  (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#environment-variables)

Only 1.59GB of memory reserved but unallocated doesn't seem like enough to cause concern, especially since the system was trying to allocated 4.81GB.
What measures can I take to make my memory usage more balanced across GPUs, or simply prevent the program from crashing even if it means skipping certain training records? Thank you!

Ended up solving this. It turns out that some of the records in my training were substantially larger (largest was over 6k tokens) than the majority (~500 tokens), and it was these records that caused the memory spikes. I removed them by using this code as I tokenized my dataset:
def tokenize_function(examples):
    prefixed_instructions = [f"translate: English to API call: {instruction}" for instruction in examples['instructions']]
    tokenized_examples = tokenizer(prefixed_instructions, text_target=examples['api_calls'], max_length=8192, truncation=True)
    
    filtered_examples = {
        "input_ids": [],
        "attention_mask": [],
        "labels": []
    }

    for record in zip(tokenized_examples["input_ids"], tokenized_examples["attention_mask"], tokenized_examples["labels"]):
        input_id, attn_mask, label = record
        if len(label) <= 2048 and len(input_id) < 2048:
            filtered_examples['input_ids'].append(input_id)
            filtered_examples['attention_mask'].append(attn_mask)
            filtered_examples['labels'].append(label)

    return filtered_examples
dataset_tokenized = dataset_split.map(tokenize_function, batched=True, remove_columns=dataset_split['train'].column_names)

I also used auto_find_batch_size=True in my training arguments to ensure efficient utilization of the GPUs.
